# AJAX - stop scrolling to top after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i tryed some things to stop scrolling the page to top after an specific ajax event but with no result. Here is an example:

```
$(".changeviewdispatch > button").each(function () {
    $(this).on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clicked_button_val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'dispatch.php',
            data: {'submitview':clicked_button_val},
            success : function (d) {
                //alert(d);
                window.location.reload(true);
            },
            //error : errorHandler
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

the page scrolls to top after click...preventDefault and return false should not work...

general question: how can i stop scrolling to top after an ajax event?

Comment: `window.location.reload(true);` is re-loading the page. No exactly a AJAX type dynamic change on page. Your question is wrong.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: the usual reason to use AJAX is so that you don't reload the page. Why are you calling `reload()` explicitly?

Comment: Your code is wrong. After the success callback you have a "," that should not be there.

Comment: if i dont reload, the page will not change the content...

Comment: You have to put the content that you requested via AJAX into the document somewhere yourself for it to show up … f.e. using [`.append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Create mainDiv after body  tag start..

2) put below code (using jquery) where you want scroll page.

```
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#mainDiv").offset().top
 }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.reload(true);` on you ajax success is reloading the page. Scroll bar will default to top on page refresh.

In true `AJAX` way if you want the page to remain static, then you need to update contents in the page based on the response from the AJAX call. If you reload the page then you are missing the point.

Hope this clears.